# Why For- in loop returns 'arg' when loop is empty

Tags: javascript, json, blackberry-10

I am iterating over the JSON Object

My JSON Structure is something like this

> {"someinfo":{"Parameter":{"ABC":"123","xyz":"456"}}}

```
 for (var tempVal in jsonObj.someinfo.Parameter) {
//print tempval

}
```

above loop will return correct values when 'Parameter' in JSON is filled.

If it is empty it will print **arg**

Empty 'Parameter' in JSON will Look Like:

> {"someinfo":{"Parameter":""}}}

In order to print correct values when empty or non empty is there any way in for- in loop

Comment: Are you talking about `if` condition ?

Comment: I would say your json parameter is incorrect. It should be an object or null. Not object or empty string.

Comment: Ok. I don't have control on JSON file Content or format. So in above condition what best can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filled `Parameter` is an `object`
empty `Parameter` is a `string`

```js
var jsonObj1={"someinfo":{"Parameter":{"ABC":"123","xyz":"456"}}};
var jsonObj2={"someinfo":{"Parameter":""}};
alert("Full: "+typeof jsonObj1.someinfo.Parameter+" ---- Empty: "+typeof jsonObj2.someinfo.Parameter)
```

you can't "loop in a string" so if you either change your JSON or test it like this

```
if (typeof jsonObj1.someinfo.Parameter==="object") {
  for (var tempVal in jsonObj.someinfo.Parameter) {
  //print tempval
  }
 } else {
  //empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if `jsonObj.someinfo.Parameter` is an object like this:

```
var json = {"someinfo":{"Parameter":{"ABC":"123","xyz":"456"}}};

if(typeof json.someinfo.Parameter === "object") {
  for(var key in json.someinfo.Parameter) {
    // print key
  }
} else {
  // Do something when it is not an object (empty)
}
```